# Using Ajax to fill a cascading dropdown list

Tags: jquery, ajax, vb.net, drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-2

I am currently working on changing the contents of a drop down list using ajax and jquery, and filling from a database. Using jquery, I can clear and add to the drop down just fine. My problem comes when trying to hit the controller to hit the database for the information needed to fill the second drop down.

How can I make this work? I've spent three days reading through other SO questions in the hopes of finding the answer, and here is the jquery code I have thus far:

```
$('#Vehicle_KovId_value').change(function () {
        var kovID = $(this).val();
        if (kovID != null && kovID != '') {
            $('#Vehicle_BodyStyle_value').get(0).options.length = 0;
            $('#Vehicle_BodyStyle_value').get(0).options[0] = new Option('Please Select One', '-1');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "AjaxController/Index",
                async: true,
                data: "{KovID:" + kovID + "}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    $('#Vehicle_BodyStyle_value').get(0).options.length = 0;
                    $('#Vehicle_BodyStyle_value').get(0).options[0] = new Option("Please Select One", "-1");
                    alert("Worked!");
                    $.each(msg.d, function (index, item) {
                        $('#Vehicle_BodyStyle_value').get(0).options[$('#Vehicle_BodyStyle_value').get(0).options.length] = new Option(item.Display, item.Value);
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    $('#Vehicle_BodyStyle_value').get(0).options.length = 0;
                    alert("Failed to load styles");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

I've tried a few different url setups in the above code, such as:

```
url: "@Url.Action('AjaxController', 'Index')",
url: "/AjaxController/Index",
url: "/Controllers/AjaxController/Index",
url: "Controllers/AjaxController/Index"
```

For reference, though we haven't really done anything with the controller yet, here's the code for the controller:

```
Namespace NoticeOfSale
    Public Class AjaxController
        Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

        '
        ' GET: /Ajax

        Function Index() As ActionResult
            Return View()
        End Function

    End Class
End Namespace
```

I'm not sure if I've just got the wrong syntax or if I'm finding syntax for later versions of MVC, as I am using MVC 2.

Comment: I realize that this is probably a dumb question to some of you, but I am very new to programming, and I'm hoping to figure this out either via answer on here or via weekend research by Monday, so I can implement the fix and have this code working soon. Once again, any help or suggestions are much appreciated! Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you used Firebug to see what's happening in your jquery code?

Comment: I can't even get Firefox to open it. I've been using IE8 and Chrome. But I'll see if I can get that figured out and try that. Great idea!

Comment: Also, I don't think you need the quotes in data: "{KovID:" + kovID + "}".  It should just be data: { KovID : kovID}

Comment: Firebug did actually help pinpoint the problem. The reason the controller isn't being called is that the program cannot find the controller location. Thank you so much, Markpsmith! That was very helpful advice indeed!

Comment: @markpsmith, Thank you for the help. I have fixed the issue of not being able to reach the controller. Not only did I have to change the url, but now I have to properly set up the controller class, as it is not accepting the `POST` type of the ajax call. Now to figure out how to set up the vb controller properly.

Comment: Great, glad you're making progress!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here was in the call.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "AjaxController/Index",
                async: true,
                data: "{KovID:" + kovID + "}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
```

Both the type and the url were incorrect. I should have been:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/Ajax/Index',
            async: false,
            data: { KovID: kovID },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
```